# Why is this Python method leaking memory?

Tags: python, memory-leaks

This method iterate over a list of terms in the data base, check if the terms are in a the text passed as argument, and if one is, replace it with a link to the search page with the term as parameter.

The number of terms is high (about 100000), so the process is pretty slow, but this is Ok since it is performed as a cron job. However, it causes the script memory consumtion to skyrocket and I can't find why:

```
class SearchedTerm(models.Model):

[...]

@classmethod
def add_search_links_to_text(cls, string, count=3, queryset=None):
    """
        Take a list of all researched terms and search them in the 
        text. If they exist, turn them into links to the search
        page.

        This process is limited to `count` replacements maximum.

        WARNING: because the sites got different URLS schemas, we don't
        provides direct links, but we inject the {% url %} tag 
        so it must be rendered before display. You can use the `eval`
        tag from `libs` for this. Since they got different namespace as
        well, we enter a generic 'namespace' and delegate to the 
        template to change it with the proper one as well.

        If you have a batch process to do, you can pass a query set
        that will be used instead of getting all searched term at
        each calls.
    """

    found = 0

    terms = queryset or cls.on_site.all()

    # to avoid duplicate searched terms to be replaced twice 
    # keep a list of already linkified content
    # added words we are going to insert with the link so they won't match
    # in case of multi passes
    processed = set((u'video', u'streaming', u'title', 
                     u'search', u'namespace', u'href', u'title', 
                     u'url'))

    for term in terms:

        text = term.text.lower()

        # no small word and make
        # quick check to avoid all the rest of the matching
        if len(text) < 3 or text not in string:
            continue

        if found and cls._is_processed(text, processed):
            continue

        # match the search word with accent, for any case
        # ensure this is not part of a word by including 
        # two 'non-letter' character on both ends of the word
        pattern = re.compile(ur'([^\w]|^)(%s)([^\w]|$)' % text, 
                            re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)

        if re.search(pattern, string):
            found += 1

            # create the link string
            # replace the word in the description 
            # use back references (\1, \2, etc) to preserve the original
            # formatin
            # use raw unicode strings (ur"string" notation) to avoid
            # problems with accents and escaping

            query = '-'.join(term.text.split())
            url = ur'{%% url namespace:static-search "%s" %%}' % query
            replace_with = ur'\1<a title="\2 video streaming" href="%s">\2</a>\3' % url

            string = re.sub(pattern, replace_with, string)

            processed.add(text)

            if found >= 3:
                break

    return string
```

You'll probably want this code as well:

```
class SearchedTerm(models.Model):

[...]

@classmethod
def _is_processed(cls, text, processed):
    """
        Check if the text if part of the already processed string
        we don't use `in` the set, but `in ` each strings of the set
        to avoid subtring matching that will destroy the tags.

        This is mainly an utility function so you probably won't use
        it directly.
    """
    if text in processed:
        return True

    return any(((text in string) for string in processed))
```

I really have only two objects with references that could be the suspects here: `terms` and `processed`. But I can't see any reason for them to not being garbage collected.

EDIT:

I think I should say that this method is called inside a Django model method itself. I don't know if it's relevant, but here is the code:

```
class Video(models.Model):

[...]

def update_html_description(self, links=3, queryset=None):
    """
        Take a list of all researched terms and search them in the 
        description. If they exist, turn them into links to the search
        engine. Put the reset into `html_description`.

        This use `add_search_link_to_text` and has therefor, the same 
        limitations.

        It DOESN'T call save().
    """
    queryset = queryset or SearchedTerm.objects.filter(sites__in=self.sites.all())
    text = self.description or self.title
    self.html_description = SearchedTerm.add_search_links_to_text(text, 
                                                                  links, 
                                                                  queryset)
```

I can imagine that the automatic Python regex caching eats up some memory. But it should do it only once and the memory consumtion goes up at every call of `update_html_description`.

The problem is not just that it consumes a lot of memory, the problem is that it does not release it: every calls take about 3% of the ram, eventually filling it up and crashing the script with 'cannot allocate memory'.

Comment: `<Pendantic>` It is nearly impossible to LEAK memory in a garbage collected language like Python. Strictly speaking, a memory leak is memory that has no variable reference to it. In c++ if you allocate memory in a class, but don't declare a destructor, you can have a memory leak. What you have here is simply high memory consumption.`</Pendantic>`

Comment: :-) Ok. Then I got a high memory consumption that gets higher and higher after each call. But since it's a method. And since I don't hold a réference to anything after it's done, why does something still consume memory ?

Comment: Updated the question about this.

Comment: just to make sure: have you verified that this call is responsible for the memory consumption?

Comment: yep: remove it and the memory stays still. Currently I'm running without it as it's not critical for the website.

Comment: I tried to use the gc module to find more about it, but gc.get_object() just saturate my screen for 5 minutes with data :-(

Comment: even if you always store something (new and large) to `self.html_description`?

Comment: To be fair, I actually stripped update_html_description, not add_search_links_to_text. self.html_description is not very large: it's a 300 char string max.

Comment: The two large objects are : the regex cache and the terms queryset.

Answer (score 3):

The whole queryset is loaded into memory once you call it, that is what will eat up your memory. You want to get chunks of results if the resultset is that large, it might be more hits on the database but it will mean a lot less memory consumption.

Comment: I'm ok with the whole queryset being in memory. It is not much: 100000 string max wrapped in a model object. After each call, it should be garbage collected anyway. The problem is that each calls CUMULATIVELY eats memory. First call take 3% of the RAM. Next call 6% and so forth.

Comment: Updated the question about this.

Answer (score 2):

I was complety unable to find the cause of the problem, but for now I'm by passing this by isolating the infamous snippet by calling a script (using `subprocess`) that containes this method call. The memory goes up but of course, goes back to normal after the python process dies.

Talk about dirty.

But that's all I got for now.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you aren't running in DEBUG.

Comment: :-) This is a prod server and DEBUG is set to False. But good catch, this is indeed known to cause memory leak and I your answer forced me to check that.

Answer (score -1):

> I think I should say that this method is called inside a Django model method itself.
>
> @classmethod

Why?  Why is this "class level"

Why aren't these ordinary methods that can  have ordinary scope rules and -- in the normal course of events -- get garbage collected?

In other words (in the form of an answer)

Get rid of `@classmethod`.

Comment: ^^ @classmethod is for a class method, that is called in update_html_description(self, links=3, queryset=None) which is an instance method. There is no confusion here.

Comment: @e-satis.  I'm sure there's no confusion.  There's also no *need*.

Comment: I added the name of the class they belong to to clarify things: SearchedTerm has a class method that linkify any text, while Video instances use this to udpate their html_description. The reason add_search_links_to_text is a class method is of course that it is a utility methods, no meant to act on SearchedTerm instances.

Comment: @e-satis. "utility methods"?  Any `class` level attribute will consume memory and bypass "typical" cleanup of an instance.  Why do this?  Why not simply make it a  simple method?

Comment: I don't use any class level attribute. And I have no reason to for ce the creation of an ORM object instance to allow somebody to linkify a text. I could make it a simple function, not related to any class though. But again, it's easier to group things related to SearchedTerm in the SearchedTerm class. I know that class attributes hold global reference. I took a lot of care no to use them.

Comment: Since you are 124K rep, I just tested the code by turning all class methods into instance methods. It didn't change anything. Given the fact that you went rather agressive, giving a wrong answer, and that I've seen you doing this several times on SO, it's a -1 for you.

Comment: @e-satis. "agreesive"?  What's aggressive?  I'm asking for clarification on why you're insisting on using class level attributes and methods when they're not called for?  You didn't provide a very compelling answer except to say that they were "utility methods" (a definition that is so overused as to be meaningless.)  The use of `classmethod` is rarely justified, particularly in a Django context where they make heavy use of a metaclass.  If that's aggressive, I apologize for trying to find an improvement.

Comment: @S.Lott let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1600/discussion-between-e-satis-and-s-lott)

Comment: apologies accepted. Just didn't want to add up comments that won't add information about the question

Comment: Was talking about the chat proposal in my last comment. Relax dude. You'll get an heart attack if you stress like this.

Comment: @e-satis: "Given the fact that you went rather agressive"  You're right.  I apologize again for whatever it is that's bothering you about the questions.